# Multiple With-Subqueries

Tags: sql-server-2008, subquery

Can I use multiple WITH-subqueries within one query?

```
;WITH x AS (
  SELECT ...
),
WITH y AS (
  SELECT ...
)
SELECT * FROM z 
INNER JOIN x ON ...
INNER JOIN y ON ...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is called [*common table expression*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx), and yes, you can use multiple CTE's, use only one `WITH` and remove the second `with` like this:

```
WITH x AS (
  SELECT ...
),y AS (
  SELECT ...
)
SELECT * FROM z 
INNER JOIN x ON ...
INNER JOIN y ON ...
```

Comment: Great! I could not find any good example in the internet :( Searching for the keyworh 'with' is not very helpfull :(

Comment: @TomasWalek The right term to use should be **SQL Server multiple CTE**, see this for example: http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/08/08/sql-server-multiple-cte-in-one-select-statement-query/

Comment: @TomasWalek Also this book: [**Microsoft SQL Server 2012 T-SQL Fundamentals**](http://www.amazon.com/Microsoft-Server-2012-T-SQL-Fundamentals/dp/0735658145) is a great book of the sql server fundamentals.

Comment: Well if you know the right seach term, searching becomes much easier :)